# Run python script inside php

Tags: php, python

I am trying to run a python script in php to test file reading so i can continue my work and do more code. I tried with a small txt file and php file but the output of python script is an empty string. All the files are in the same directory and i am using XAMPP in VISTA OS.

php file

```
<?php

$validation= exec('python script.py juliodantas.txt') ;
echo $validation ;

var_dump($validation);

?>
```

python file: (script.py)

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"

import sys
fich_input= sys.argv[1]

def test(fich):
    input_fil=open(fich,'r')
    s=''
    cont=0
    for line in input_fil:
        cont+=1
        s+=line
    return (line,cont)

test(fich_input)
```

txt file is tab formated file  (juliodantas.txt)

CAS Smiles  InchI   Mol_name    LAB Institution Species Cell_type   Subcellular Bio_target  Conditions  Asay_parameter  Observations    Assay_ID    strain  Tissue  target_type value   Unity   Comparisons Experimental_error
12233   535 2435d   3r5rg   4t4t    4t  4t34t4  4t4t4   4trgdf  vgery4  345y4   grfbg   gergh   hj6yu   wde kukl    derj,.i gjyy    htht5u  thyt5   tht56   thtrj4yeg

**the output of php:**

```
string(0) ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may quote the [manual for `exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> The last line from the result of the command.

Your Python program prints out `"Content-Type: text/html\n"`, so the last line of its output is an empty line.

If you want the whole output of the program inside a variable, use the second, optional parameter of `exec`:

```
$validation = "";
exec('python script.py juliodantas.txt', $validation);

echo impode("\n", $validation); // should print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
```

**Update:**

I've previously used the deprecated (and apparently, now removed) call-with-pass-by-reference syntax. Shame on me. Also, apparently `exec()` returns the output as a line-based array, so you've got to join it if you want to have it as a single string.

Comment: i changed to passthru and now the output is: NULL

Comment: It doesn't print anything more.

Comment: I can't understand why :/

Comment: @JoãoPedro Sorry, my bad. I didn't pay enough attention. This should work now.

Comment: Now it prints this error : Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bioinformatica\processa_tsv\AJAX_upload\teste.PHP on line 4.                                                                                              Line 4 is:  exec('python script.py juliodantas.txt', &$validation);

Comment: @JoãoPedro Yeah that's a bit old. Now I've tested it, and it works.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation step by step :)